# Cyclomatic Complexity Number

Tags: java, numbers, complexity-theory

Hi iam just learning the Cyclomatic Complexity and i dont get it.
I have read some wikipediaposts and some random posts on the internet and there are always different solutions i think.

First of all What do I count.
On many pages it says that i should begin with an 1 for the function and then add for each if i find is this correct?

http://docs.klocwork.com/Insight-10.0/McCabe_Cyclomatic_Complexity
So in this equals the CCN should be 5 is this correct or did i miss something?
I just dont get it what to count and what not since there are so manny different posts on the internet.
Sry if this question is asked bevore but i was not able to find it.

So have a nice Sunday and enjoy ur time
Is there like a simple "trick" how to see it very fast.. just wondering

http://s16.postimg.org/ufouegwut/number.png)
This is the link to the snipped i hope it is not a problem that i not just wrote the code here

Comment: The `equals()` method that you supplied in the PNG is not polymorphic in the sense that it prohibits instances of subclasses to be equal to instances of other subclasses or the base class. While this may be intentional, this is unusual, just wanted to tell. I'd have written this this function as `return this == obj || obj instanceof User && id == ((User) obj).id;`

Answer (score 1):

The cyclomatic complexity of a function is the number of paths the code can take through the function.

The example you point to:

```
Function 
  While
    If
    Else
    Endif
  Endwhile
End Function
```

Has the cyclomatic complexity of 3, this is because there's a path of not hitting the while, a path hitting the while, and a path hitting the if inside of the while (the else is part of the previous path that hit the while but not the if).

I find the simplest way is to count the number of possible branches: `while`, `for`, `if`, `switch` cases (not including the `default` case), `catch`, and ternary operators, then add 1.

Here are the branches that [GMetrics](http://gmetrics.sourceforge.net/gmetrics-CyclomaticComplexityMetric.html) counts:

- if statement
- while statement
- for statement
- case statement
- catch statement
- && and || boolean operations
- ?: ternary operator and ?: Elvis operator.
- ?. null-check operator

**Edit:** Just noticed your example was actually at the end of your post, which as you correctly say has a cyclometric complexity of 5 as you have 4 branches (4 if statements), so 4 + 1 = 5